# How accurate is the JavaScript Date module on a client?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, client, utc

I'm reconciling dates sent from the client to my server, and while I can obviously rely on my server's datetime, it's an open question about the client's.

How accurate is the `Date.prototype.toUTCString()`? Does it apply the proper UTC offset to the client time and provide that, or does it do something more verifiable?

Comment: It's only as accurate as the clock on the client computer.

Comment: `toUTCString` surely doesn't check the actual time agains a server or anything, it just takes the computer clock, figures out the timezone, and subtracts or adds to get UTC time. In other words, it's exactly as Barmar noted, it's only as accurate as the clients computer, if you need something more accurate just output a current unix timestamp in your page/app and use that.

Comment: thanks to you both for the confirmation!